# Can an Oracle with Heavens mystery use FlyBy Attack

Tags: pathfinder-1e, feats, class-feature

If an oracle with the heavens mystery chooses the Lure of Heavens revelation, does the supernatural fly give you a fly speed to qualify for the feat Flyby Attack?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would be able to take this feat at 10th level. As the Lure of the Heavens description says:

> At 10th level, you gain the ability to fly, as per the spell

The fly spell gives you a fly speed.

> The subject can fly at a speed of 60 feet (or 40 feet if it wears medium or heavy armor, or if it carries a medium or heavy load).

The previous benefits of Lure of the Heavens (feet not touching the ground, levitating) do not.